# What does assignment in while condition check?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```
while(a = foo())
{
    bar();
}
```

Is this checking:

- If assignment is successful, run bar, or
- If a is defined and non-null, run bar, or
- Something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every iteration, it assigns the result of the `foo()` call to `a`, and if that result was truthy, it runs the loop and tries again until the result of the call is falsey.

For example, while assigning inside a condition is generally a code smell, it's seen often enough when trying to iterate over capture groups in a global regular expression:

```js
const str = 'abcdefg';
const pattern = /(.)./g;
let match;
while (match = pattern.exec(str)) {
  console.log('first captured group was ' + match[1]);
}
// after the last iteration, `match` is null, so the loop stops
```

If the assignment is *not* successful, and the cause of that non-success would throw an error, then the whole script stops due to the error. (unless there's a `try` / `catch` block around it)